# Why does MongoDB updateMany require brackets?

Tags: mongodb

Why does this not work? It sets `newfield` equal to the string "$oldfield" and not the value of the field `oldfield`

```
await db
    .collection('events')
    .updateMany(filter, { $set: { newfield: '$oldfield' } });
```

Why are brackets needed?

```
await db
    .collection('events')
    .updateMany(filter, [{ $set: { newfield: '$oldfield' } }]);
```

Comment: It does work. However you mistake https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v6.2/reference/operator/aggregation/set/ with https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/set/

Comment: To second WD - it does work, but likely not as you expect. Asking such questions, it's better to explicitly say what is the expected result and what is the actual result / error message. Just "doesn't work" leaves no chance for detailed answer.

Comment: I updated my question. I still don't understand the difference.

Comment: Open both pages WD referenced and compare. I doubt there is a better way to explain the difference. The first query uses regular update to set value to a field, the second query uses aggregation expression to calculate value at runtime.

Comment: OK I guess I'll just never understand why the `$field` notation only works in an aggregate format. Thanks anyway.